# Is fishing line mekabel-tumah? Can it be used in schach?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, schach

סכך cannot be made of a דבר המקבל טומאה, there is a company that make a reed mat that is held together (מעמד) with fishing line and it comes with instructions to put some wood on top of it so that it will be held down even without it. The reason being that since fishing line is מקבל טומאה we don't want it to be מעמד the סכך, hence the question is fishing line really מקבל טומאה? why?

Answer (score 2):

So [Star-K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/seasonal/431/guide-to-star-k-certified-schach/) brings a good breakdown based on a psak of Rav Moshe Heineman:

> In Hilchos Sukkah ([Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 629:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.629.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) it is written that schach can not consist of something that is “mekabel tumah” (something that has the ability to become ritually impure). It is for this reason that bamboo carpet mats cannot be used for schach as they are mekabel tumah. All Star-K certified schach is not made to sit or walk on and is therefore not mekabel tumah.
>
> In addition, l’chatchila, kosher schach may not be supported by anything which is mekabel tumah (see [Rama O.C. 629:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.629.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). According to the opinion of Rashi (as brought in [Shaar Hatziyun 629:20](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60391&st=&pgnum=180&hilite=)) spun or woven threads (e.g. string, yarn) are mekabel tumah. Rav Moshe Feinstein states ([Igros Moshe, O.C. 1:177](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=296&hilite=)) based on a Mishna, if something which is mekabel tumah is used to hold wooden slats together, the slats themselves are also mekabel tumah and are no longer kosher for schach use. Therefore, Rav Moshe Feinstein explains that wooden venetian blinds held together with cloth tape or string are not kosher for schach. It follows that according to Rashi bamboo slats held together by multi-filament cord (i.e. it is braided or twisted) are also not kosher for schach (even if they are not made to sit or walk on).
>
> However, monofilament (commonly used for fishing line) is not woven or spun material. Therefore, it is not mekabel tumah and may be used to hold bamboo slats together. All Star-K certified bamboo schach is held together with monofilament cord.

So based on this, it would only be an issue if the string is woven or spun which would make it mekabel tumah. If it isn't it would be allowed to hold the slats together.

Comment: so the instructions are wrong? it is star-k schach that comes with this instructions...

Comment: Ooh that's awkward! I would call them for clarity and ask them based on the posting on their website. It seems pretty definitive there?

Comment: The citation you link to for the Shaarei Tzion, in the body text, only excludes cordage made from cotton. That made from dried reeds or bulrush, like modern day sisal twine are permitted. This is related to the level of processing for the finished cordage. Cotton cordage is like a finished, highly refined tool. Sisal, which is less processed, is like twigs pulled from the ground and is thus not considered capable of receiving tumah.

Comment: For additional clarification, סיב, which is also permitted as cordage for Skach is made from the bast of palm. This linked video demonstrates what is being described in Shulchan Aruch. https://youtu.be/gELlns9IO1U

Comment: One further clarification for those who might not understand why cotton cordage is different relates to how cotton cordage is manufactured. The following 3 videos demonstrate the complex, multi-stage process involved in producing cotton cordage from cotton boll picked from the plant, to bale, to yarn, and then finally to cordage (including rope). Step 1) https://youtu.be/QHgNoSYlhYs

Comment: Step 2) Making cotton yarn: https://youtu.be/kH_b3Heo48I

Comment: Step 3) Making cotton cordage from the cotton yarn: https://youtu.be/WHxGzzSjuuU

Comment: After reviewing all of the above comments and linked videos, it should be clear why cotton cordage is distinct as a finished tool which is capable of becoming tameh, while cordage made from reeds or palm bast and similar cordage, like sisal, is not considered a refined, finished tool capable of becoming tameh and can be used in securing skach.

Comment: On the subject of monofilament, it is an extruded petroleum product. It doesn’t grow from the ground and is not naturally occurring. In keeping with the view of Rav Moshe Feinstein (Orach Chaim, Vol.2, 92 s.v. Uvadavar kli) it would seem to fall into that category of a refined, finished tool which can become tameh in keeping with the fact that plastics in general are capable of absorbing. This is observed by anyone who has heated tomato sauce in a plastic container. In that context, monofilament should be avoided in binding skach.